# macbook pro does not see bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, boot, usb

A friend's macbook pro 2008 no longer boots its windows installation. It is double booted to mac and windows

To fix the problem (attempt startup repair) I created a USB drive using Rufus 2.5

[image]

USB does not come up as an option in the boot menu. There is a post which outlines how to install windows http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/install-windows-on-mac/ instructing to create a bootable drive using mac.

How can I create a bootable win 7 usb without using a mac to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Windows 7 USB Tool from Microsoft

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

It has never failed making a bootable USB for me.  I just tried it with windows 7 on a MacBook and it booted up perfectly.  Just hold the option key as the Mac turns on to see the available disks and the USB should show up there. Mine was called Windows 7.

Comment: didn't work -- says my iso file is invalid

Comment: Might need to get a new ISO.  That could also be why Rufus is not working, perhaps

Comment: I think it rather has to do with some codesigning or verification process that windows undertakes

Comment: is there a place where i can download a new one from microsoft?

Comment: You'll need a product key, but here is the site https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows7